# Recalculating the radius

Tags: geometry

I have this steering scheme. Is it possible to calculate $r_o$ if I have $r_b$, $c$ and $b$?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No. There seems to be no relation between points $A$ and $B$, so we can not use $r_b$ to infer $r_0$.

$c$ and $b$ seem to offer no help either.

Comment: Is there any approximation formula? I can build a triangle with point A and B.

Comment: So you have the coordinates of $A$ and $B$? And what else do you have to determine the triangle? Two points are not enough to determine a triangle.

Comment: Yes, I do. Actually $A$ — is the center of the wheel and $B$ — is marker on car's body. Both of them either calculable or have fixed coordinates. I think I can get coordinates of the center using triangle $rbc$ and point $A$.

May be you give me an idea what point/angle would be sufficient?